# Remove maximal cliques in igraph

Tags: r, igraph, clique, clique-problem

I have a disconnected undirected network.
I want to identify and **remove all the components that are cliques**.
I do *not* want to remove all the cliques, just those that are themselves a component of the network.

How should I proceed?

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_literal(a-b-c-d-b,e-f-g-e,h-i-l)
result <- graph_from_literal(a-b-c-d-b,h-i-l)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is the following, but I do not know to what extent this is efficient in large networks.

```
d <- graph_from_literal(a-b-c-d-b,e-f-g-e,h-i-l)
d0 <- decompose.graph(d)
d1 <- disjoint_union(d0[unlist(lapply(d0, function(x) count_max_cliques(x)!=1))])
```